# marginal probabilities, multivariate random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, marginal-probability

I want to solve the task below...
However, I have a problem with the marginal probabilities not adding up to 1.

what's wrong?

[image: MySolution]

Answer (score 1):

Order matters.

For $(0,1)$, it should be $2 \cdot \frac36 \cdot \frac16$ as we can switch the order.

Similarly, probability for $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ needs to be multiplied by $2$.

Comment: Ah, I See. Thank you.